# how to distinguish tokens which have similar patterns in Lexer, but they occur in different contexts in the parser

Tags: parsing, haskell, lexer, happy

I have two pretty similar patterns in Lexer.x first for numbers second for byte. Here they are.

```
$digit=0-9
$byte=[a-f0-9]


    $digit+                       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $digit+.$digit+               { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $digit+.$digit+e$digit+       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $digit+e$digit+               { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $byte$byte                        { \s -> TByte (encodeUtf8(pack s))     }
```

I have Parser.y

```
%token

        cnst                            { TNum  $$}
        byte                            { TByte  $$}
        '['                            { TOSB     }    
        ']'                            { TCSB     }

%%

Expr: 
 '[' byte ']' {$1}
| const {$1}
```

when I write, I got.

```
[ 11 ] parse error
11 ok
```

but when I put byte pattern in Lexer before numbers

```
$digit=0-9
$byte=[a-f0-9]

    $byte$byte                        { \s -> TByte (encodeUtf8(pack s))     }
    $digit+                       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $digit+.$digit+               { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $digit+.$digit+e$digit+       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
    $digit+e$digit+               { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
```

I got

```
[ 11 ] ok
11 parse error
```

I think that happens because Lexer makes tokens from string and then gives them to parser.
And when parser wait for byte token it got number token and parser don't have opportunity to make from this value another token.
What I should do in this situation?

Comment: In that case you should postpone parsing it to a `TNum` or `TByte` but present it as a token that can be a number/byte, like `TNumValue` for example, and let the parser interpret it as byte/integer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you should postpone parsing. You can for example make a `TNumByte` data constructor that stores the value as `String`:

```
Token
    = TByte ByteString
    | TNum Rational
    | TNumByte String
    -- …
```

For a sequence of `$digit`s, it is not yet clear if we have to interpret this as byte or number, so we construct a `TNumByte` for this:

```
$digit=0-9
$byte=[a-f0-9]

$digit$digit                  { TNumByte }
$byte$byte                    { \s -> TByte (encodeUtf8(pack s)) }
$digit+                       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
$digit+.$digit+               { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
$digit+.$digit+e$digit+       { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
$digit+e$digit+               { \s -> TNum  (readRational s) }
```

then in the parser we can decide based on the context:

```
%token

  cnst                           { TNum $$ }
  byte                           { TByte $$ }
  numbyte                        { TNumByte $$ }  -- 🖘 can be int or byte
  '['                            { TOSB }
  ']'                            { TCSB }

%%

Expr
  : '[' byte ']' { $2 }
  | '[' numbyte ']' { encodeUtf8(pack $2) }  -- 🖘 interpret as byte
  | const { $1 }
  | numbyte { readRational $1 }  -- 🖘 interpret as int
  ;
```